# How can i change the border radius of a check box in material-ui?

Tags: css, reactjs, checkbox, material-ui

I imported material-ui in my react app and i can change the color and size of a checkbox as you can see but i can't change the icon borderRadius, how should i do that?

````
import FormGroup from '@mui/material/FormGroup';
import FormControlLabel from '@mui/material/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';

const CheckBox = () => {
    return <div>
        <FormGroup>
            <StyledFormControlLabel
                control={
                    <Checkbox
                        sx={{
                          '& .MuiSvgIcon-root': {
                                fontSize: 70,
                                borderRadius: 20
                            }
                        }}
                    />
                }
                label="Villa"
            />
        </FormGroup>
    </div>
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** change the border-radius as it is an SVG when rendered.

[image: HTML of checkbox]

Therefore it is not possible to do this via the border-radius.

If you want to change it you have to insert your icon like this:

```
<Checkbox icon={<CustomCheckbox/>} .../>
```

Here a link to the documentation [Checkbox with custom icons](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-checkbox/#icon)

Answer (score -1):

MUI has the corresponding components which you can use depending on your use case.
See [the link](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-dew-6ox1qb?file=/src/App.js:0-794) and code below.

```
import FormGroup from "@mui/material/FormGroup";
import FormControlLabel from "@mui/material/FormControlLabel";
import Checkbox from "@mui/material/Checkbox";
import CircleChecked from "@material-ui/icons/CheckCircleOutline";
import CircleUnchecked from "@material-ui/icons/RadioButtonUnchecked";
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <FormGroup>
        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Checkbox
              icon={<CircleUnchecked />}
              checkedIcon={<CircleChecked />}
              sx={{
                "& .MuiSvgIcon-root": {
                  fontSize: 70,
                  borderRadius: 20
                }
              }}
            />
          }
          label="Villa"
        />
      </FormGroup>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Incorrect. The Checkbox border-radius does not change regardless of the `sx` parameters.